# not equal sign not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using not equal sign to convert false to true but it is always giving false. I have tried it with 0 and 1 which is working fine. Also when I am changing value "False" to "true" then it is also working but problem is with "false" only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test= "False";
alert(!test)
</script>
```

Comment: That's because you're using strings, not actual booleans...

Comment: The string "False" is truthy. JavaScript isn't THAT loosely typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the string `"False"`, assign the boolean `false`

```
var test = false;
alert(!test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put quotes around your boolean, you actually make a string of it.
You should do it like this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = false;
    alert(!test)
</script>
```